# Display firestore object array as option in multi-select

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-select

I'm trying to display data in Firestore as options in a multi-select. I'm trying with this:

```
  const retrieveNetwork13 = async () => {
    try {
      //const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "cities"));

      const q = query(collection(db, "schedule"));

      const qq = query(q, where("uid2", "==", uid3));

      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(qq);

      setRead01(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().schedule));
     
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveNetwork13();
  }, []);
```

Then to set the options of the multi-elect:

```
  const options = read01.map((val) => ({ value: val, label: val }));
```

Heres the multiselect:

```
 <MultiSelect
                  labelledBy="Hora"
                  name="user_select7"
                  value={options.filter((obj) => date1.includes(obj.value))}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  options={options}
                />
```

The problem is that I get one option with the array altogether. Please some help. Don't know what else to do. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Andres, could you please include how you render your multi-select. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. I just edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `Multiselect` library you're using but you added the `react-select` tag in your question. I would suggest using the [**React Select**](https://react-select.com/home) library instead.

Install it by using this command:

```
npm i --save react-select
```

and, try this instead:

```
  import Select from 'react-select';

  const [read01, setRead01] = useState([]);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([]);

  const retrieveNetwork13 = async () => {
    try {
      const q = query(collection(db, "schedule"));
      const qq = query(q, where("uid2", "==", uid3));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(qq);

      setRead01(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().schedule));
     
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  };

  // handles dropdown onChange event.
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(Array.isArray(e) ? e.map(x => x.value) : []);
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveNetwork13();
  }, []);

  const options = read01.map((val) => ({ value: val, label: val }));
```

To render:

```
      <Select
        isMulti
        value={options.filter((obj) => selectedValue.includes(obj.value))} // Sets selected value
        options={options}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        placeholder="Select Option"
      />
```

For more information you may check the official documentation [here](https://react-select.com/home).